# How to override some function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have my wordpress setup on IIS and it is rewritten. Because of that I found some probably bug in wordpress in `wp_includes/canonical.php` file.
I think that when I update my wordpress that all my changes will disapear. I can't wait for wordpress fix this (I don't even know if it is bug or how to report one) because that "bug" causes my homepage to go in redirect loop.
 I made some change in `redirect_canonical` function in that file specificly this change:

```
function redirect_canonical( $requested_url = null, $do_redirect = true ) {
///some other code 
if ( ! $requested_url && isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) ) {
        // build the URL in the address bar
        $requested_url  = is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        //$requested_url=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] //I deleted this because my URL is rewritten 
    $asParts = parse_url( $sURL ); // PHP function
        $requested_url .= $asParts['host'] ;
        $requested_url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

How to make this change resistant to wordpress updates?

Comment: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-bugs/

Comment: _“I have my wordpress setup on IIS and it is rewritten. Because of that I found some probably bug in wordpress”_ - hm, I rather doubt it ... I think you might have rather found a bug in your rewrite setup. What exactly goes wrong then, if that line you mentioned is left in? What does `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` actually contain?

Comment: "I think that when I update my wordpress that all my changes will disapear" - of course, updating WordPress will overwrite all of its core files. That's not a bug. Avoid changing core files, chances are there's a [filter / action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks:_Actions_and_Filters) that does exactly what you need.

Comment: I am not wordpress developer, can you elaborate? I currently had to change core file because homepage (production url) was not working because of that.

Comment: What does that mean? :)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress have the hooks concept to change the core functions and process. All hooks are defined via `apply_filters` and `do_action`. The hooks are different in filter `apply_filters` and action - `do_action`.

You should read about: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks

You should never change the core, because maintenance, function and more. In your example function `redirect_canonical` have also hooks, like `redirect_canonical` ([Doku](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/redirect_canonical/)) ([in source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/aaf99e691391cfceb004d848450dbbf3344b1bee/wp-includes/canonical.php#L571)). However it give much more and it is in depends on your goal, requirements.

As small example to change the return value of the function via the filter hook see the code example below.

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', function ( $redirect_url, $requested_url ) {

    // I don't know what is the var $sURL in your code.
    $requested_url = parse_url( $sURL );
    // Leave here the logic to change the result for $redirect_url.
    return $redirect_url;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Where to make my changes? I don't know anything about wordpress development. Only to set it up

Comment: The knowledge is in the link from the codex. It is not possible only answer with a code snippet to solve that problem.

Comment: It is also not possible to positively vote on answers that have quality just above "google the solution" ;)

Comment: I gave not the answer to Google the solution, all necessary links, the only one, is inside the answer. It is not possible to give an solid answer for your question in a code snippet. It is necessary that you understand the api.

Comment: However you can ask again with details in the goal and requirements for this one function to solve in a easy way.